# Pandas - Drop NaN's per column and pad with 0 fast?

Tags: python, pandas, lstm, zero-padding

I have a data frame such as the following with tens of thousands of rows and a thousand columns:
[image]

For an LSTM, I would like to

1. extract the values only per column,
2. put them together at the beginning of the dataframe and
3. pad 0 before the values start up to index 99.

However, please note, not every column has the same amount of values. Some have already a lot, some have none yet. Also on which timestamp the values are generated is column specific. I did achieve the result with the following code. However, since the code is really slow (700 hours), **I am looking for a possibility to execute the calculation logic faster.** It takes so long, since I want to calculate this kind of result for each hourly timestamps from 2008 to 2020.

**Is there any way to make the code significantly faster?**

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(index=range(100),columns=dummydata.columns)
for j in dummydata.columns:
    df1[j]=dummydata[(dummydata.index<=i)][j].dropna().iloc[-T:].iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
df1=df1.fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data along with expected output? It makes extremely difficult to provide an answer when the original result is unknown. Besides, what are `i` and `T`?

Comment: sorry, that code bit was part of a larger code. i is an iterator in a for loop and iterates through all timestamps in chonological order. T = 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this to see if this is faster?

`dummydata.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).fillna(0)`

Then you can select only the first 100 rows using `dummydata.loc[0:100, :]`

Comment: Thanks - that works and achieve the desired result really fast.